# "Column 'model_id' cannot be null" Django Cascade

Tags: django

Estou com um problema em deletar 2 foreign keys de uma foreign key. Vou explicar melhor:

Essa é a hierarquia da model de cartão de credito que tenho:

- CreditCard
- - Customer
- - - Address
- - - Phone

Estou tentando deletar o endereco e telefone, logo em seguida customer e creditcard. Está dizendo que nao posso alterar para null a foreign key **address** e **phone** da model **customer**.

```
(1048, "Column 'phone_id' cannot be null")
```

Ele esta tentando fazer um update na coluna phone_id e address_id setando para NULL. O erro era esse, a operação não é permitida. Então atribui `null=True, blank=True` na model de customer e o erro continua.

Tentei dessa forma:

```
_credit_card.customer.phone.delete()
_credit_card.customer.address.delete()
_credit_card.customer.delete()
_credit_card.delete()
```

Python 3, Django 1.10

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca aqui o código do seu `models.py` referente a essas tabelas. Verifique se você rodou o comando `makemigrations` e `migrate` após as alterações.

Comment: As variáveis dos modelos que contém essas `ForeignKey`s contém o CASCADE no on_delete? `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/

Comment: @Orion fiz o makemigrations e makemigrations e migrate sim. As models estão exatamente como mostro na hierarquia. Duas models.ForeignKey de UserAddress e UserPhone. Isso tudo dentro da model Customer que é uma foreign key de CreditCard.

Comment: Você não colocou o código do model completo. Se você não tiver colocado o `on_delete=models.CASCADE` na FK do seu modelo, ele não vai chamar a função em cascata e pode gerar o seu erro.

Comment: Eu coloquei o `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. Já ajustei o erro. O problema real é que eu estava atrelando o address e phone dentro do customer. Na verdade precisava ter um customer dentro dessas 2 tabelas. Ai sim, deletando o Customer, eu deletaria as 2 tabelas também.

Answer (score -1):

Eu identifiquei o problema. Eu tinha as 2 foreign key (UserPhone e UserAddress) dentro da tabela Customer como foreign key. Mesmo usando o `on_delete=models.CASCADE` não estava funcionando. Foi só eu tirar essas 2 foreign key e criar a foreign key do **CUSTOMER** dentro de cada uma das tabelas que funcionou. Deletando Customer, eu deleto as 2 tabelas em cascata.